# Do I need to go to a dealer for a simple maintenance?

Tags: honda, maintenance, oil-change, replace, dealer

I just bought a 2012 CRV. Now, it's time for an oil change. I already moved so the dealer is too far away from my house (may need half day off) and there is no other public transportation to go there. My guess is the cost is about the same or more with other shops such as mida's.

Do I need to go the Honda Dealer? I am not sure whether it will break any warranty. This is my first car so please bear with me.

Answer (score 9):

At least in the United States you are not required to use the dealer for service,parts or repairs to maintain your warranty. You will be required to have the warranty work done at the dealer except in extenuating circumstances,(like the nearest dealer is 150 miles away) but you must still contact them first. If they deny a warranty claim on the basis of non dealer service you can take legal action. You are required to maintain the vehicle at the factory intervals. Most independent shops now have the ability to check the service requirements for your vehicle on line if you don't have an owners manual. Maintain a record of any work that is done. All that is needed to maintain the warranty is proof that the required service was done. This means you can do the work yourself, keep a record of what,  when etc.

Comment: I would add, however, that I would seek reputable brand specialist even if smaller independent shop. We have had some bad experiences with chain shops (specifically the one OP mentioned), where they would not do such a simple task to top off the coolant in my fiancée’s car which caused it to overheat and crack a cylinder head.

Answer (score 2):

Why not change the oil yourself?

It is a very easy task and allows you to become a little more familiar with your new CRV. You save a few dollars, get the pride of working on your own car, and become more knowledgeable about the specifics of your vehicle.

It usually doesn't take more than 30 mins to change your own oil. It's done with nearly all hand tools. I'm not familiar with the height of the CRV off the ground, but you don't normally need to jack up SUVs or Pickups.

Doing simple maintenance will most likely not void your warranty so long as you do it correctly and keep your receipts.

Comment: Suggestion is a valid comment, and a good idea, but it doesn't answer the OP question.