# In Canada, would doing my own oil change void the warranty?

Tags: oil-change, warranty

I'm looking to see if someone can confirm that changing the oil on my car will not void the warranty (I'm in Canada). Links for proof would be nice or get an idea where to look for such things.

[This post talks about the United States](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/do-i-need-to-go-to-a-dealer-for-a-simple-maintenance), and I assume that it should be the same as in Canada.

I've done it in the past with our older car, but I started when the warranty had expired. I feel comfortable doing it on the new car, however, don't want to run the risk of voiding the warranty.

Comment: Not sure of the answer, but I _really_ hope the answer is NO everywhere in the world.

Comment: I'm assuming that it's a no, provided that I can document it properly.

Comment: I have no idea what the right answer is, but while I hope it's no, I would not be at all surprised if it's yes. From their point of view it gains their dealers more work, and prevents warranty claims when someone screws it up.

Comment: @cdunn Agreed. I've had warranty claims (busted crank shaft bearings) after having had my car serviced by a licensed shop (had all my receipts). Not worried about that and would take it to a shop I trust before the dealer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could call your dealership and ask them. They may try to talk you out of it and get you to come in, don't get suck into that. I have warranty at a Subaru dealership here and they said it's all good if I do my own oil changes, but I have to keep the receipts/records of it.

In case something does go wrong with your motor, at least you will have proof of all your oil changes. Certain dealerships may have different policies though so it wouldn't hurt calling them up.

Comment: Got in touch with my contact which mentioned that I would be okay with the receipts. For future references, this was a Mazda dealership.