# New Car Oil Change

Tags: scheduled-maintenance, warranty

So I bought my first new vehicle, a 2016 Jeep Renegade Latitude.  The oil change message came up.  I called the dealership to get some pricing and info and they were simply intolerable.  Would it be a breach of my warranty to take it to a regular shop?

Comment: Nope, you can take it anywhere or do it yourself. It's wise to keep the receipt though, since it won't be documented in the dealership computer.

Comment: at least provide feedback on why it is a bad question...

Answer (score 2):

**PROBABLY not**

If you change your oil yourself or have a shop do this for you, save the receipt.

If your engine blows up you will want to provide proof that you were getting the oil changed.

Beware, the dealer may claim incompetence of an oil change to get out honoring their warranty but I haven't heard of those type of tactics in years.  There is a risk of that occurring though.   Understand that there is a risk of that happening.

You can also call the dealership and simply ask them if that will void your warranty and get the facts.  That would be my first step.

Comment: Unfortunately(or fortunately really) this question has already been answered here too [Do I need to go to dealer...](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/do-i-need-to-go-to-a-dealer-for-a-simple-maintenance).  It probably should be removed.

Comment: @FelixCastor  Vote to close it and I'll follow up with the same.  Good looking out  TY.